# Instagram API paginator

Tags: php, pagination, instagram

Ok, so after a few months of building a site i'm on the final stretch and i hit my first unclimable wall.

I would like to add pagination to this page.. http://hooligansforlife.com/bands.php?info=All%20Projects&sub=Fan%20Feed at  24 images per page, but everything i have tried (i have tried for hours!) has failed.

I hate to be cheeky, but i am out of ideas

Thank you in advance, the code i am using follows..

```
<table cellspacing="7"><tr>
<?php
$count = 0;
function callInstagram($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
CURLOPT_URL => $url,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2
));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
}

$tag = '[tag]';
$client_id = "[id]";
$url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/[tag]/media/recent?client_id=[id]&count=24';

$inst_stream = callInstagram($url);
$results = json_decode($inst_stream, true);

//Now parse through the $results array to display your results... 
foreach($results['data'] as $item)
   {
    $image_link = $item['images']['thumbnail']['url'];
    $author = $item['caption']['from']['username']; 
    $link = $item['link'];
    $date = $item['created_time'];
    $likes = $item['likes']['count']; 
    $comments = $item['comments']['count'];
    ?>

    <td onmouseout="this.style.opacity=1;" onmouseover="this.style.opacity=0.7;" class="content_box"><a  href="<?php echo $link; ?>" target="_blank">
    <table cellspacing="1">

    <tr><td colspan="2"><img src="<?php echo $image_link; ?>"></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="show_with_field" style="padding-left:5px; width: 110px;"><strong><?php echo $author; ?></strong>

        </td>
    <td class="discography_date" valign="bottom"><img height="8" src="images/main/like.png" width="8"> :  <?php echo $likes; ?></td></tr>

    <tr><td style="padding-left:5px; width: 110px;" class="discography_date"><?php echo date("jS F Y",$date); ?></td>

    <td class="discography_date" valign="bottom"><img height="8" src="images/main/comment.png" width="8"> :  <?php echo $comments; ?></td></tr>
    </table></a></td>

    <?php
    $count++;

    if ($count >= 6)
    {
    echo '</tr><tr>';
    $count = 0;
    }
}
?>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you want to paginate with buttons or with endless scrolling? Instagram provides a "next_url" property in their API results -- you could just add a $_GET param to your page to handle next_url?

Comment: I hadn't thought about endless scroll. Is it possible without jscript.

Comment: No, it's not. Has to be done client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we look at the documentation there is not way to define the number of items returned

```
http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/
```

You should save the results in a database, then make a query directly into your database to retrieve items by 24.
For example, you can use a cron job to keep your database up to date.

Comment: Thanks, i created a database which grabbed data from instagram and twitter. It works very well, I even included a look up to monitor to see if the user had deleted any tweets/images. Got the end result :)